PLS-00364: el uso de la variable 'V_INGRESO_DATOS' de índice de bucle no es válido PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Estoy haciendo un procedimiento con cursor que llama a otras funciones para llenar un tabla en ORACLE. Cuando intento hacer mi for me da error y ya no sé qué hacer; todo lo demás me compila.
EL error que me da es el del título:

PLS-00364: el uso de la variable 'V_INGRESO_DATOS' de índice de bucle no es válido
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Este sería mi script:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UTILIDAD_PACIENTE (p_anno in DATE) IS  
    CURSOR c_calculitos IS 
    SELECT p.codigo_pac AS codigo, p.fecha_nac AS fecha, COUNT(a.codigo_pac) AS conteo_atenciones
    FROM atenciones A JOIN paciente P
    ON P.codigo_pac = a.codigo_pac 
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.fecha_operacion) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_anno)
    GROUP BY codigo
    ORDER BY codigo DESC;

    v_sql1 VARCHAR2(255) := 'TRUNCATE TABLE resumen_utilidades_pacientes';   
    v_sql2 VARCHAR2(255) := 'TRUNCATE TABLE errores_proceso';  
    
    v_msg VARCHAR2 (225);
   
    v_error NUMBER ;
    v_aten_dental      NUMBER :=0;
    v_cod_pac          NUMBER :=0;
    v_anno_cal         NUMBER := EXTRACT (YEAR FROM p_anno);

  --otras variables--
    
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql1 ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 ;
    
    FOR v_ingreso_datos IN c_calculitos LOOP
        v_error := v_ingreso_datos.codigo;
        v_total_aten := FN_TOTAL_ATENCIONES( v_ingreso_datos.codigo , v_anno_cal);

       -- variables mas --
        
        INSERT INTO resumen_utilidades_pacientes VALUES ( v_ingreso_datos.codigo,v_anno_cal,v_ingreso_datos.atenciones, v_total_aten, v_desc_edad,v_desc_pediatra,v_total_ingreso);
        
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;

    -- excepción--
    
END UTILIDAD_PACIENTE;
/


Hay algún otro mensaje de error antes del PLS-00364? Pregunto porque usualmente este da si el cursor es inválido, pero hay un mensaje anterior que indica esa situación.

¿Por qué hacer un bucle cuando se podría hacer el insert directamente con un INSERT INTO .... SELECT ...?

por que es un requerimiento usar el bucle :c

El problema está en la declaración del cursor, lo cual debió darte un error anterior, pues el campo p.fecha no está incluido en la agrupación, ni en una función de agregación en la consulta.
Debes agregarlo a la agrupación o bien llamar a una función de agregación para tener un cursor válido, por ejemplo:
CURSOR c_calculitos IS
    SELECT   p.codigo_pac AS codigo
           , p.fecha_nac AS fecha
           , COUNT(a.codigo_pac) AS conteo_atenciones
      FROM atenciones A 
           JOIN paciente P ON P.codigo_pac = a.codigo_pac
     WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.fecha_operacion) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_anno)
     GROUP BY p.codigo_pac, p.fecha_nac
     ORDER BY p.codigo_pag DESC, p.fecha_nac;

O bien
CURSOR c_calculitos IS
    SELECT   p.codigo_pac AS codigo
           , min(p.fecha_nac) AS fecha
           , COUNT(a.codigo_pac) AS conteo_atenciones
      FROM atenciones A 
           JOIN paciente P ON P.codigo_pac = a.codigo_pac
     WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.fecha_operacion) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_anno)
     GROUP BY p.codigo_pac, p.fecha_nac
     ORDER BY p.codigo_pag DESC, p.fecha_nac;

La regla general es que debes tener una sentencia select válida en la declaración del cursor.
Ya después de ello, la sentencia for compilará sin problemas:
  for v_ingreso_datos IN c_calculitos 
  loop
    -- bla, bla, bla
  end loop;


Algunas correcciones
La consulta en el cursor está inválida por una o dos razones:
GROUP BY con alias
Generalmente, GROUP BY codigo no puede funcionar, porque no hay una columna codigo en las tablas. Tienes un alias aquí: SELECT p.codigo_pac AS codigo, pero la cláusula SELECT esta progresado después de la cláusula GROUP BY, entonces el alias esta todavía desconocido en GROUP BY.
Esto es conforme con el standard SQL y siempre ha estado así en Oracle también. Hay otros DBMS que permiten un alias en GROUP BY y Oracle también lo permite desde la versión 23ai. Entonces depende de tu versión de Oracle si hay un problema o no.
Entonces en DBMS Oracle antes de la versión 23ai:
GROUP BY p.codigo_pac

Seleccionando la fecha
Tienes un GROUP BY p.codigo_pac, así creando un resultado con una fila por codigo_pac. Seleccionas ese código, la p.fecha_nac, y una agregación COUNT(a.codigo_pac). Hay tres posibilidades:

El codigo_pac es una llave única para la tabla paciente, y piensas que si dices al DBMS que quieres una fila por codigo_pac, puedes seleccionar la fecha del mismo registro. Si es así, tienes razón. Así debe funcionar, porque la fecha esta funcionalmente dependiente del código. Pero Oracle tiene problemas con la detección de la dependencia funcional y por eso requiere que todas las columnas están en la cláusula GROUP BY o están agregados. Entonces necesitas un pseudo MAX(p.fecha_nac) o MIN(p.fecha_nac) o GROUP BY p.codigo_pac, p.fecha_nac.
El codigo_pac no es una llave única para la tabla paciente, y quieres un resultado con una fila por codigo_pac. Entonces, si hay más de un registro por codigo_pac, ¿cual fecha de seleccionar? ¿La mínima? ¿La máxima? ... Tienes que decirlo en la consulta, por ejemplo: MAX(p.fecha_nac).
El codigo_pac no es una llave única para la tabla paciente, y quieres un resultado con una fila por codigo_pac y fecha. Entonces no es suficiente tener GROUP BY p.codigo_pac, porque esto produce un resultado con una fila por codigo_pac. Si quieres un resultado con una fila por codigo_pac y fecha_pac, tienes que escribir: GROUP BY p.codigo_pac, p.fecha_nac.

Por fin: el mensaje del error
Es muy raro que recibes el error

PLS-00364: el uso de la variable 'V_INGRESO_DATOS' de índice de bucle no es válido

No importa cuál versión de Oracle usas, Oracle debería mencionar un error en la consulta en vez y hacer inválida el procedimiento. Bueno, en realidad esto funciona en versiones antes de Oracle 23ai:

ORA-00904: "CODIGO": invalid identifier

Demostración: https://dbfiddle.uk/g3uK5BD8
En la versión Oracle 23ai, el alias en la cláusula GROUP BY ya no es un problema, pero la fecha todavía es. Sin embargo Oracle no produce un error en crear el procedimiento. En vez produce un error cuando la usamos:

ORA-00979: "P"."FECHA_NAC": must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Demostración: https://dbfiddle.uk/uV_8Jz-m
Esto no debería ser así, y en mi opinión es un defecto en esta versión del DBMS. Oracle no debe hacer válido el procedimiento, si tiene un error en el cursor. Tiene que producir en mensaje de error en vez.
